# How to concatenate two params using href?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have kendo grid where i am using anchor tag so using href i am trying to pass two params from client side but it always give syntax error, any help what is correct way to pass variables using href.

config.js

```
toolbar: [{template: '<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right"  
      href="app/challenge/rest/exportChallengeGridDataToExcel?key={{$rootScope.id}}  
        &challengeType={{$rootScope.challengeType}}">Export to Excel</a>'}]
```

Comment: what error u get....?

Comment: I would recommend you to extract that to a function

Comment: i did extract that to function before but there i have other problems i get blob content in response but its not prompting to for download in browser so i came with this approach

Comment: Can you console.log challengeType and prcs_id and see a value or are they undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like :

```
'<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right"  
href="app/challenge/rest/exportChallengeGridDataToExcel?key={{$rootScope.id}}  
&challengeType={{$rootScope.challengeType}}">Export to Excel</a>
```

Anyways I would encourage you to use $rootScope as less as possible, also to build your URL in your controller so your html looks more readable, but that's up to you

Comment: I used your approach but its still not working getting syntax error illegal token , edited my question.

Comment: Could you make a code snippet in jsbin or plunker? So I can help you? Also try changing the href by ng-href, just in case

Comment: it worked for me without curly braces, Thanks for the help